# Unzip the .zipx format In AIX (Unix)

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I am trying to unzip the '.zipx' file in Unix. I have tried `unzip`, `gunzip` and `tar` commands but nothing is working.

Can anybody please help on this?

Answer (score 5):

In 7za 16.02 it is possible to unzip a zipx file in unix

```
7za e fileName.zipx
```

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 18.04 with `7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02`

Answer (score 1):

Try [p7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), according to the [changelog](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) it should be able to extract zipx files since version 15.05 beta.
You might need to compile the newest version yourself if the binary version from sourceforge doesn't work, as the available (unofficial) [aix binary](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.P7zip) is older then that.

Comment: p7zip 15.14 says zip and zipx are unknown.

Comment: I was able to extract a zipx finally.  I used the package p7zip-full_15.14.1-4~ppa~trusty_amd64.deb -- but don't use the "p7zip" command.  There is a binary named "7a" that I had to use instead and then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a windows-only format. One option you have if you can only access it on a Unix box is by running WinZip through [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)